# Odd color filling with gradient in Highstock areaspline

Tags: highcharts

see the picture and code below. 
It seemed that if the high value point happened to in line, the line color would be filled in the surrounded area.
No any idea yet!
Thanks advance for any help.

[image: odd gradient color filling]

```
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false,
            color: '#07b062',
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#1e1e26',
                lineColor: "#07b062"
            },
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.Color('#07b062').setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color('#07b062').setOpacity(0.0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

one more
[image]

Comment: Please provide the data that you use in your chart.

Comment: It seemed to be related with the screen size. I saw several times in user's screen, but I could not reproduce the issue in my device screen.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official response, it was an issue related to the Chrome.
Here's the workaround:

```
.highcharts-series path {
    stroke-linecap: initial; 
}
```

See more discussion:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7662